# Zoom and marker

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

I have UIScrollView with UIImageView on it. On UIImageView I have round marker(one more UIImageView), which I can drag on UIImageView. I want to zoom my image on UIImageView, so:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return imageView;
}
```

But when user is trying to zoom image my marker is zooming too. But I want to see my marker in its original size. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply reverse zooming transform to your marker in delegate's method:

```
- (void) scrollViewDidEndZooming: (UIScrollView *) aScrollView withView: (UIView *) view atScale: (float) scale{
    marker.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f/scale, 1.0f/scale);
}
```

Or in `scrollViewDidZoom:` method - depending on which one will give better behaviour for you